# Android - cloning an Animation object

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm building a asynchronous `RecyclerView` and I want to inflate its items asynchronously and display them one after another with some delay. I've done that. For an item, I have a `CustomView` to display its layout. Inside this `CustomView`, after a specific delay, I add the `View` that I get from an `AsynchronousInflater` to a `Framelayout` that I inflated synchronously. I can add it with an animation, like this:

```
view.animation = AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f).apply { duration = 300 }
framelayout.addView(view)
```

Ok. The problem is that the animation is hardcoded inside this `CustomView`. What I want is to pass an animation to the `Adapter` and the `Adapter` to pass it further to the `CustomView` (inside `onCreateViewHolder`, let's say). It would be very neat if I could have something like this:

```
val adapter = CustomAdapter(
    someList,
    AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f).apply { duration = 300; }
)
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

The problem with this approach is that every item inside the `RV` would use the same `Animation` instance. Which is not correct. All the items will be animated at the same time. I should have a different instance for each item. I thought of some workarounds to solve my issue, but they are very ugly. A not so ugly solution (but maybe inefficient) would be to clone the `Animation` object inside every `RV` item. Any thoughts or solutions on this are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The answer is the accepted answer from the first question that I have asked on SO. Instead of passing an `Animation` object and then clone it, I should pass to the `Adapter` a method that tells it how to create an `Animation` object for each `View`. Instead of using

```
val adapter = CustomAdapter(
    someList,
    AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f).apply { duration = 300; }
)
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

I should use

```
val adapter = CustomAdapter(
    someList,
    { AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f).apply { duration = 300; } }
)
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```